# Codeigniter set_value() With Dynamic Multidimensional Array Inputs

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

OK, I am generating a form which is pre-populated with existing values from the db:

View:

```
    <tr>
      <td><input name="set[<?php echo $cur_set['id']; ?>][order]" value="<?php echo $cur_set['wo_order']; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="set[<?php echo $cur_set['id']; ?>][ex_id]" value="<?php echo $cur_set['ex_id']; ?>"></td>
      <td><input name="set[<?php echo $cur_set['id']; ?>][weight]" value="<?php echo $cur_set['weight']; ?>"></td>
      <td><input name="set[<?php echo $cur_set['id']; ?>][reps]" value="<?php echo $cur_set['reps']; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
```

Example output:

```
    <tr>
      <td><input name="set[3][order]" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="set[3][ex_id]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input name="set[3][weight]" value="50.00"></td>
      <td><input name="set[3][reps]" value="5"></td>
    </tr>
```

So I have a range of these `<tr>`s each can have a unique 'id' but all have the same number of secondary indices `[order], [ex_id], [weight]` and `[reps]`.

I cannot figure out 2 things:

1. How to apply the set_value() syntax when I don't know what the [id] is going to be.
2. How to set validation rules on the form. I have tried:

   ```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('set[][order]', 'Sets', 'required');
   ```

but it doesn't seem to work as `set[][order]` is not found...can I put some sort of wildcard in there? Like `set[*][order]`?

Thanks in advance.

Jon

Comment: Can you explain more, especially this: `So I have a range of these <tr>s each can have a unique 'id' but all have the same number of secondary indices [order], [ex_id], [weight] and [reps]` **and** `How to apply the set_value() syntax when I don't know what the [id] is going to be`

Comment: You can try use `input name="order[]"`, and modify set_rules `order`.

Comment: @Amir I am fetching data from db, then splitting it into individual `<input>` for each row. So each row has an `id`,`order`,`weight`,`ex_id` and `reps`. So each `<tr>` contains inputs named as `set[(id)][(order/ex_id/weight/reps)]` so I can modify them and they know which set[id] they belong to. But because the id is unique, I cannot see how I write a validation rule when I don't know what the id is. I need some sort of catch-all for `set[?][order/ex_id/weight/reps/]`. Hope that makes sense

Comment: OK, think I found a solution:
`foreach($data['sets'] as $set_id) { $this->form_validation->set_rules('set['.$set_id['id'].'][order]', 'Set Order', 'required'); }

Comment: and here is how I solved the set_value in my view: `<input name="set[<?php echo $cur_set['id']; ?>][order]" value="<?php echo set_value('set['.$cur_set['id'].'][order]', $cur_set['wo_order']); ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, where you fetch the data and store it in a variable (I'll call it $data), do this:

```
$data = $this->MODEL_NAME->METHOD_NAME();

foreach($data as $set){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("set[{$set['id']}][order]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("set[{$set['id']}][weight]");
    etc...
}
```